# Capture IntegrityError in Django Dynamic Fixture

Tags: django, django-unittest

I'm trying out [Django Dynamic Fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture) (DDF). It has a few of its own Exceptions, one being [BadDataError](http://django-dynamic-fixture.readthedocs.org/en/latest/more.html?highlight=baddataerror#list-of-exceptions), generated when "the data passed to a field has some problem (not unique or invalid) or a required attribute is in ignore list".

For example, this

```
# Entry.text is models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False, blank=False)
G(Entry, text=None)
```

will generate a `BadDataError`, as Django will raise an `IntegrityError` (text cannot be None).

I guess DDF captures the `IntegrityError` and wraps it in its `BadDataError` exception as the error I get is

```
django_dynamic_fixture.ddf.BadDataError: ('core.models.Entry', IntegrityError('NOT NULL constraint failed: core_entry.text',))
```

The issue is that I would like to test for an `IntegrityError`. How would I be able to do so while still using DDF?

Comment: Why would you want to use DDF in that case?